# Ruby create new hash from another hash with specific values from first hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below hash from webhook requests:

```
   webhook = {"environment"=>"master",
     "entity_type"=>"item",
     "event_type"=>"publish",
     "entity"=>
      {"id"=>"5267370",
       "type"=>"item",
       "attributes"=>{"title"=>"new text webhook", "is_separate_activity"=>false, "short_description"=>"webhook", "long_description"=>"new text webhook", "text"=>["5267545"], "author"=>"test", "reading_time"=>"4 min", "updated_at"=>"2020-07-06T13:25:30.599+01:00", "created_at"=>"2020-07-06T12:41:45.495+01:00"},
       "relationships"=>{"item_type"=>{"data"=>{"id"=>"245189", "type"=>"item_type"}}, "creator"=>{"data"=>{"id"=>"7243", "type"=>"user"}}},
       "meta"=>{"created_at"=>"2020-07-06T12:41:45.495+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2020-07-06T13:25:30.599+01:00", "published_at"=>"2020-07-06T13:25:30.599+01:00", "publication_scheduled_at"=>nil, "first_published_at"=>"2020-07-06T12:41:45.511+01:00", "is_valid"=>true, "status"=>"published", "current_version"=>"9718212"}}}
```

I need to store only basic information from that hash:

`webhook.dig('entity', 'id')`,

`webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes', 'separate_activity')`,

`webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes', 'title')`,

`webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes', 'short_description')`

and save it in to Session model as `t.json "content_basic"`. Is there any nifty way (maybe one line?) to grab few key/value pairs to another hash?

Comment: `#values_at` maybe ? `webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes').values_at('short_description', 'separate_activity', 'title')`

Comment: Not out of the box. search for 'ruby deep_slice'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need anything shorter than this:

```
entity = webhook.dig('entity')

data = {
  id: entity['id'],
  is_separate_activity: entity.dig('attributes', 'is_separate_activity'),
  title: entity.dig('attributes', 'title'),
  short_description: entity.dig('attributes', 'short_description'),
}

Session.create(content_basic: data.to_json)
```

You might refactor to this but not sure what you're really saving.

```
keys = [ 'short_description', 'is_separate_activity', 'title' ]
values = webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes').values_at('short_description', 'is_separate_activity', 'title') 

data = { id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id') }
keys.each_with_index{|k, i| data[k] = values[i]}
```

Comment: Be careful with `Hash#dig` as it might return `nil` so there would need to be handling for those instances.

Answer (score -1):

```
e = webhook['entity']
ea = e['attributes']
[e['id'], ea['separate_activity'], ea['title'], ea['short_description']]
  #=> ["5267370", nil, "new text webhook", "webhook"]
```

I recommend against using `dig` when the hash structure is known and the nested keys should all be present, for the simple reason that it's preferable to have an exception raised when a hash does not have a key that should be present than for `dig` to quietly return `nil`. One could of course investigate (in code) if `dig` returns `nil`, but what's the point when it's so easy to just raise an exception?

If `h` is a hash and

```
h[:a][:b][:c] #=> nil
```

we know, because no exception was raised, that `f = h[:a]` `g = f[:b]` are hashes but either `g` has a key `:c` whose value is `nil` or `g` does not have a key `:c` (as with `ea['separate_activity']` above, for example). In this case, therefore, if `g` is known to have a key `:c` with a non-nil value, an exception should be raised. This is still preferable to using `dig`, for

```
h.dig(:a, :b, :c) #=> nil
```

tells us only that there was a problem was encountered somewhere in the excavation.